# How to tile multiple images

Tags: image-editing

I need to tile multiple images into one image such that there is no space between any of the adjacent images. Is there any software out there which provides me this facility?

Answer (score 1):

Imagemagick has a ["montage" tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#montage) to do this. It is available for Unix, Linux, Mac and Microsoft-Windows.

```
 montage font_[0-9].gif  -geometry 16x16+1+1  tile_0.gif
```

The +1+1 is the gap (actually empty border) between component images, you can set this to zero.

[image: example]